# jetty 9: setting up the most basic SSL / https

Tags: grails, ssl, jetty

**NOTE:  If you want to see the behaviour of this demo app, just go to www.collaborativepowernowinternational.us.  Here, select the testssl.PersonController, and you may create a person.  Then go and edit the person, where the SSL channel is designated, which will give a redirect loop.**

It seems like with Jetty 9 more configuration items went into the start.ini file, I have version 9.05.

In order to test the most basic SSL/https, I am uncommenting the following lines in start.ini:

```
#===========================================================
# SSL Context
# Create the keystore and trust store for use by
# HTTPS and SPDY
#-----------------------------------------------------------
jetty.keystore=etc/keystore
jetty.keystore.password=OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4
jetty.keymanager.password=OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g
jetty.truststore=etc/keystore
jetty.truststore.password=OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4
jetty.secure.port=8443
etc/jetty-ssl.xml

#===========================================================
# HTTPS Connector
# Must be used with jetty-ssl.xml
#-----------------------------------------------------------
jetty.https.port=8443
etc/jetty-https.xml
```

No other Jetty configuration changes.  I then built the most basic Grails app (has a Person class) where I set certain controller actions to secure, which works fine on my development machine using an older built in Jetty version (that Grails includes).  This is done simply by including spring-security-core and then adding the following lines to a configuration file:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
  '/person/list': 'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL',
  '/person/delete/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
  '/person/edit/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
  '/person/show': 'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL'
]

grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort=80
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort=443
```

When I access the person/edit action I get a redirect loop in the browser (using deployed WAR file to Jetty 9 on dedicated CentOs 6 machine).  This is using the provided keystore that comes with Jetty 9, just uncommenting the lines in start.ini to use it.

The main Jetty SSL configuration page I'm reading is [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory).  What isn't clear to me is, is updating the start.ini file enough?  If not, how exactly does one add the lines in jetty-https.xml described in this previous link, i.e. the lines:

```
 <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
 </New>
```

Not sure how to add them, but they also seem a duplicate of the start.ini file lines above.

Can you please help help me get the most basic Jetty SSL running?   Thanks much.

---

If not familiar with Grails, one can simply download it, then create a domain class -- there is a command line option for this.  Then give it fields String firstName, String lastName.   Then there are commands to generate a controller and views for it -- this is all totally automatic.  Then one adds the plugin, spring-security-core.  In chapter 16/17 of this doc and as I have shown, when lists which controller actions are secure, such as person/edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have enough here for just the Jetty portion of this to be working using the default trial keystore we ship in Jetty 9.0.6 distribution.

Simply the blurb you have above is enough to make SSL work within Jetty.  I downloaded the 9.0.6 distribution and uncommented those lines and it works.  Well, I had to go into the start.d/demo.ini file and remove the last two lines with etc/jetty-ssl.xml and etc/jetty-https.xml because they would get run twice...but I digress.

If you start up Jetty you can navigate to `https://localhost:8443` and it will complain about being an untrusted certificate and then load up the jetty distribution page.

Based on that I would say this is likely some sort of grails configuration issue that I sadly don't know the answer too, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that Grails allows a way to specify secure channels that works "on the desktop" with an older Jetty version via plugin, but does not work in the newer Jetty versions (that I am deploying too).  That issue in combination with the the flux of how to turn on SSL and specify certificates between the Jetty 9.05/9.06 (via start.ini) and the newer Jetty 9.10 version threw me off - couldn't get anything working.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the right version to use -- i.e. 9.06 for the time being, as the configuration mechanism for 9.10 is finalized and associated documentation is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Jetty 9.1, things have changed, and you have to follow the instructions in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-base-and-home.html) for things to look correct, per Jetty developers. Moreover, you are not supposed to change/delete/edit anything in `${jetty.home}`'s directories. Here's what you need to do for a self-signed certificate based SSL/HTTPS on Jetty 9.1+:

(a) set up your environment variable `$JETTY_HOME` to point to where you installed your jetty tar bundle, say `/opt/jetty/`.

(b) Create a new directory, `/tmp/myJettyApp`, point it to `$JETTY_BASE` in your environment.

(c) cd to `$JETTY_BASE`

(d) Follow instructions in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html):

```
/home/sonny $ cd $JETTY_BASE
/tmp/myJettyApp/ $ java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-startd=https,http2
```

(e) Set your port if you'd like:

```
/home/sonny $ cd $JETTY_BASE;
/tmp/myJettyApp/ $ java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar jetty.ssl.port=8444
```

(f) And now, run jetty:

```
/tmp/myJettyApp/ $ java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar
```

you will see that HTTPS is running at port 8444. Now, if you want to make jetty  listen in the traditional HTTPS port, you have to use sudo to run:

```
/tmp/myJettyApp/ $ java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar jetty.ssl.port=443
/tmp/myJettyApp/ $ sudo java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar
```

Note that this already does the self-signed certs etc. automagically.

Now, if you want to generate your own self-signed certificate (say, because you want to modify the `validity` to an arbitrary large or small value, depending on your needs), follow the instructions in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html), generate a new self-signed cert using `keytool` and then place it in `$JETTY_BASE/etc/` and modify the `$JETTY_BASE/start.d/ssl.ini` for `jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword` and `jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword` respectively. BTW, for the last two `ssl.ini` passwords, you can use the obfuscated plain text password you used when you ran `keytool` or use the plain text ones. If you want to obfuscate them, run `{jetty.home} $ java -cp lib/jetty-util-9.3.6.v20151106.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password "MyInterestingAndAwesomePassword"`

Hope this helps someone.